# PDO is not allowing insert query to be done

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am facing a weird issue that is causing me to go crazy. I never run into anything like this. even though I can predict that it will be something really easy but I am over looking it.

I am executing queries based on the business roles logic. so in somecases i do select and update, in others i do a select, update and then insert so on an so fourth. Here is the overall structure on how I handle my code

```
Open PDO connection

1 getDataSet 1 (select)
2 ProcessQuery (update)
3 getDataSet 1 (select)
4 ProcessQuery (Insert)

Close PDO connection by setting the PDO object to null.
```

For odd reason the insert does not work at all! the select works, the update works no problem but when it comes to the insert part it does not work. it does not even give me any error at all. In fact, I copied the same query and executed it in phpMyAdmin and the query works!

I should note the the table that I am trying to insert into is very large and has over 4 million records with many indexes.

What could be the problem? what else can I check? why the insert is not working form the script and it is working from phpmyadmin??

here is my code

this is my current PDO class that I use to connect to the server
http://pastebin.com/XQ2RrhA1

```
<?php

class connection {

        private $connString;
        private $userName;
        private $passCode;
        private $server;
        private $pdo;
        private $errorMessage;
        protected $lastQueryTime;
        protected $lastQuery;

        private $pdo_opt = array (
                                                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                                                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                                                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
                                                        );


        function __construct($dbName, $serverName = 'localhost'){

                //sets credentials
                $this->setConnectionCredentials($dbName, $serverName);

                //start the connect
                $this->startConnection();

        }

        function startConnection(){


                        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->connString, $this->userName, $this->passCode, $this->pdo_opt);

                        if( ! $this->pdo){

                                $this->errorMessage  = 'Failed to connect to database. Please try to refresh this page in 1 minute. ';
                                $this->errorMessage .= 'However, if you continue to see this message please contact your system administrator.';
                                echo $this->getError();
                        }
        }


        //this will close the PDO connection
        public function endConnection(){

                $this->pdo = null;
        }

        //return a dataset with the results
        public function getDataSet($query, $data = NULL)
        {
                $start = microtime(true);
                $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );

                $cmd->execute($data);
                $ret = $cmd->fetchAll();
                //$cmd->closeCursor();
                $this->lastQueryTime = microtime(true) - $start;
                $this->lastQuery = $query;

                return $ret;
        }



        public function processQuery($query, $data = NULL)
        {
                $start = microtime(true);
                           //$this->pdo->beginTransaction();
                $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );
                $ret = $cmd->execute($data);
                           //$this->pdo->commit();
                           //$cmd->closeCursor();
                $this->lastQueryTime = microtime(true) - $start;
                $this->lastQuery = $query;

                return $ret;
        }


        //return last insert id
        public function lastInsertId($name = NULL) {
                if(!$this->pdo) {
                        return false;
                }

                return $this->pdo->lastInsertId($name);
        }


        public function getOneResult($query, $data = NULL){
                $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );
                $cmd->execute($data);

                return $cmd->fetchColumn();
        }

        public function getError(){
                if($this->errorMessage != '')
                        return $this->errorMessage;
                else
                        return true;  //no errors found

        }

        //this where you need to set new server credentials with a new case statment
        function setConnectionCredentials($dbName, $serv){

                switch($serv){

                        case default:
                                $this->connString       = 'mysql:host='.$serv.';dbname='.$dbName.';charset=utf8';
                                $this->userName         = 'USER';
                                $this->passCode         = 'PASSWORD';
                        break;



                        }

        }


public function lastQueryTime() {
    if(!$this->lastQueryTime) {
        throw new Exception('no query has been executed yet');
    }
    return $this->lastQueryTime;
}

public function lastQuery() {
    if(!$this->lastQuery) {
        throw new Exception('no query has been executed yet');
    }
    return $this->lastQuery;
}



}



?>
```

This is my actual code

```
<?php
require('../classes/connection.php');

$db = new connection(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_HOST);

$sendUpdate = 0;
$id = 0;
$resultCode = 0;
$callCode = 0;
$total_attempts = 0;
$account_id = 0;
$timer = 0;

$notes = '';
$triggerOn = '';
$subject = '';

if(isset($_POST['sendUpdate'])){
        $sendUpdate = 1;
}

if(isset($_POST['current_call_id'])){
        $id = bigint($_POST['current_call_id']);
}

if(isset($_POST['result_code_menu'])){
        $resultCode = bigint($_POST['result_code_menu']);
}

if(isset($_POST['selected_call_code'])){
        $callCode = bigint($_POST['selected_call_code']);
}

if(isset($_POST['total_attempts'])){
        $total_attempts = bigint($_POST['total_attempts']);
}

if(isset($_POST['account_id'])){
        $account_id = bigint($_POST['account_id']);
}

if(isset($_POST['notes'])){
        $notes = trim($_POST['notes']);
}

if(isset($_POST['triggerOn'])){
        $triggerOn = convertTimeToUTCzone( $_POST['triggerOn'], USER_TIME_ZONE );
}

        $subject = $resultCode;


if(isset($_POST['timer'])){
        $timer = convertTimeToSeconds($_POST['timer']);
}

//CONVERT $time to seconds

        $error_list = '';
        $pass_message = '';

        if($id  < 1){
                $error_list .= '<li>You have selected an invalid link</li>';
        }

        if($callCode == 0){
                $error_list .= '<li>You must select a call code.</li>';
        }

        if($resultCode == 0){
                $error_list .= '<li>You must select a result code.</li>';
        }

        if($timer == 0){
                $error_list .= '<li>You can not reset timer before submitting the form.</li>';
        }      




        //if pass all check
        if($error_list == ''){

                $pass_all = 0;


                //Find out what is the next action
                        $action = $db->getDataSet('SELECT result FROM result_codes WHERE result_code_id = '.$resultCode.' LIMIT 1;' );

                                if( count($action) == 1){
                                        $next_action = $action[0]['result'];
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #95: Unknown Error: result code was not found.</li>';
                                        $pass_all = 0;
                                }




                //Close existing open phone call
                if( $next_action == 'FINISH' || $next_action == 'CREATE NEW CALL'  || $next_action == 'TRY AGAIN' ){

                        $statment = $db->processQuery('UPDATE phone_calls SET result_code_id= ?, call_notes= ?, call_duration = ?,
                                                                                  first_attempt_on = if(first_attempt_on IS NULL,  NOW(), first_attempt_on),
                                                                                  first_attempt_by = if(first_attempt_by = "", '.USER_ID.',first_attempt_by),
                                                                                  last_attempt_on = NOW(), total_attempts = total_attempts+1, status=2 WHERE phone_call_id = '.$id.' LIMIT 1;'
                                                                                  , array($resultCode, $notes, $timer) );

                                if($statment){
                                        $pass_all = 1;
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #96: System could not update Phone Call</li>';
                                        $pass_all = 0;
                                }
                        $statment = null;
                }




                //Update the existing phone call & Keep it open to be called again
                if( $next_action == 'TRY AGAIN'){


                        $new_call = $db->getDataSet('SELECT call_code_title AS subject FROM call_codes WHERE call_code_id= '.$callCode.' LIMIT 1;' );

                                if( count($new_call) == 1 ){
                                        $subject = $new_call[0]['subject'];
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #79: Unknown Error: call code was not found.</li>';
                                }
                        $new_call = null;
                        $this_attempt = $total_attempts+1;

                        if($this_attempt >= 1){
                                $subject = $subject . ' attempt: ' . $this_attempt;
                        }



                                        $statment = $db->processQuery('INSERT INTO phone_calls (account_id, call_code_id, trigger_on, created_on, call_subject, status, last_call_id
                                                                                , call_direction, owner_id, workflow_generated, call_notes)
                                                                                                                 VALUES('.$account_id.', '.$callCode.', "'.$triggerOn.'", NOW(), "'.$subject.'", 1, '.$id.', "OUTBOUND", '.USER_ID.', 1, "");');                                                                                                                                         



                                if($statment ){
                                        $pass_all = 1;
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #80: System could not generate a new attempt</li>';
                                        $pass_all = 0;
                                }
                $statment = null;

                }



                //Update the existing phone call THEN assign the activity to the master user define in APP_configuration.php
                if( $next_action == 'MGR REVIEW'){


                        $statment = $db->processQuery('UPDATE phone_calls SET result_code_id= ?, call_notes= ?, call_duration = ?,
                                                                                  first_attempt_on = if(first_attempt_on IS NULL,  NOW(), first_attempt_on),
                                                                                  first_attempt_by = if(first_attempt_by = "", '.USER_ID.',first_attempt_by),
                                                                                  last_attempt_on = NOW(), total_attempts = total_attempts+1,
                                                                                  trigger_on = ?, owner_id = '.CMS_ADMIN_ID.' WHERE phone_call_id = '.$id.' LIMIT 1;'
                                                                                  , array($resultCode, $notes, $timer, $triggerOn) );

                                if($statment){
                                        $pass_all = 1;
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #98: System could not update Phone Call</li>';
                                        $pass_all = 0;
                                }
                $statment = null;
                }


                if($sendUpdate == 1 && $error_list == '' && $pass_all == 1 ){

                $statment = $db->processQuery('DELETE FROM phone_calls WHERE last_call_id = '.$id.' LIMIT 1;');

                                if($statment){
                                        $pass_all = 1;
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #81: System could not run reverse system flow.</li>';
                                        $pass_all = 0;
                                }                      
                $statment = null;
                }






                //Generate new phone call
                if( $next_action == 'CREATE NEW CALL'){

                        //Find the nect call code to generate

                                $new_call = $db->getDataSet('SELECT ie.action_id, CONCAT(cc.call_code_name, " - ", cc.call_code_title) AS subject FROM inventory_engine AS ie
                                                                                         INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON ie.action_id = cc.call_code_id
                                                                                         WHERE ie.call_code_id= ?  AND ie.result_code_id = ? LIMIT 1;', array($callCode,$resultCode ) );

                                if( count($new_call) == 1 ){
                                        $new_callcode_id = $new_call[0]['action_id'];
                                        $subject = $new_call[0]['subject'];
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #94: Unknown Error: call code was not found.</li>';
                                }

                                $new_call = null;

                $statment = $db->processQuery('INSERT INTO phone_calls (account_id, call_code_id, trigger_on, created_on, call_subject, status, last_call_id
                                                                                , call_direction, owner_id, workflow_generated, call_notes)
                                                                                                                 VALUES(?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, 1, ?, "OUTBOUND", ?, 1, "");',
                                                                                                                 array($account_id, $new_callcode_id, $triggerOn, $subject, $id, USER_ID ) );

                                if($statment){
                                        $pass_all = 1;
                                } else {
                                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #99: System could not update Phone Call</li>';
                                        $pass_all = 0;
                                }
                $statment = null;
                }


                if($pass_all == 1 && $error_list == ''){
                        $pass_message = '<li>You have successfully complete the phone call.</li>';
                } else {
                        $error_list .= '<li>Error #100: Unknown Error: Please contact your system admin</li>';
                }

        }


//close database connection
$db->endConnection();


        $return = array();
        if($pass_message != ''){

                $return['msg']   = '<ul>'.$pass_message.'</ul>';
                $return['error'] = false;

        } else {
                $return['msg'] = '<ul>'. $error_list.'</ul>';
                $return['error'] = true;
        }


echo json_encode($return);






?>
```

This here is my actual code the does not insert a records

http://pastebin.com/QSt03qqx

Thanks for your help :)

PS
this is the query that won't run in my code but it runs when i run it in PHPmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO phone_calls (account_id, call_code_id, trigger_on, created_on, call_subject, status, last_call_id , call_direction, owner_id, workflow_generated, call_notes) VALUES(11601, 1, "2013-04-11 16:36:00", NOW(), "Initial Development attempt: 1", 1, 17132, "OUTBOUND", 1, 1, "");
```

Comment: Please could you add some code to the question?

Comment: yes add some code and try to catch the exception, it will help you debug

Comment: check for errors at each stage. switch pdo over to exception or warning mode, and start checking return values/try-catching, yada yada yada. without any code we can NOT help you.

Comment: I have updated my post and added 2 links one for the connection class and another once for the code where I user my queries

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Put the code *IN* the question, don't link offsite.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, no errors at all!

Comment: @Sammitch I just pasted my code in this post

Comment: About the error codes: It would be more helpful to do `'<li>Error #'.__LINE__.': ...` so you can get the actual line number dynamically.

Comment: @JoeFrambach an exception can do it already and even with call stack

Comment: @Mike how can you run the very same query in PHPmyadmin if your queries are parameterized ones?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have removed the paramenters for the perpose and then display that query just so I can see the full query. either way it is not running from my script

Comment: If you have a particular query that doesn't run, why didn't you post it here?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I just posted that query in my post above. I just executed it via php my admin and no problems

Comment: @JoeFrambach The problem is that I don't get error at all it tells me that "You have successfully complete the phone call."

Comment: Just before the line, `if( $next_action == 'CREATE NEW CALL'){`, add `echo $next_action` and see what it actually contains.

Comment: status is probably a reserved word but you have to get an exception from it. it seems your error reporting is broken

Comment: @JoeFrambach I get TRY AGAIN  Notice TRY AGAIN, CREATE NEW CALL, FINISH, AND MGR REVIEW are an enum field in the database so they always the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What could be the problem? what else can I check? why the insert is not working form the script and it is working from phpmyadmin?

Welcome to programmer's word.
As a matter of fact, programming is not only *writing* code.
But, unfortunately, up to the 50% of programmer's time being spent answering the very questions you asked above. And it's not an easy job. Considerable efforts have to be spent. The bad news, such a kind of questions scarcely can have an answer on a Q&A site. What'd you answer yourself? So, your own hands are your last resort. Thus roll up your sleeves and start for debugging:

1. Make sure you can see every error PHP raises.
2. Make sure PDO does throw an exception on error.
3. Make sure you aren't gagging these errors with `@`, `try..catches` and zero error reporting.
4. Set up watchdogs to log erroneous queries, their data and get diagnosis from mysql (at least SHOW PROCESSLIST).

Comment: I have been doing that for 2 days already which lead me to you guys for help :)  I am displaying all php errors or warnings and have none! I am displaying the error from my PDP and get no errors. I check my Processlist to see if there is anything that is locking the table but there is nothing!  Is there something that I need to add to my connection class to close or free up resources? may be because I am using one query after another after another it may be causing confusing to what it being handled! I have tried to use the closeCursor but that did not help!

Comment: if it's a live site, you have to log errors instead of displaying them. or you'd lost 99.99% of them

Comment: it is a live site on a local network so it is for internal use only. How can I log the errors and where can i see them at?

Comment: I got it finally.   I change the whole code around I think the problem was with the delete statement and not the insert and the delete was undoing everything the insert is doing...   Thanks a lot for your help guys :)